# AngularJS get rootScope variable when set

Tags: angularjs, watch

In a project I'm working on we've got a variable on the `$rootScope` called `events`. I can access this in my controllers using `$rootScope.events` after injecting it to my controller.

It can take some time before the service sets the events on the `$rootScope` variable. Now am I adding a new functionality that needs the ID from the first event of the variable. The problem is, it's getting called before `$rootScope.events` is set. I can't figure out how to call the method in my controller after the `$rootscope.events` is set. I have used `$watch` before, how ever, it doesn't seem to work on this variable. The code I tried:

```
$scope.$watch('$rootScope.events', function() {
    if ($rootScope.events.length > 0) {
        getDetails(); // function I want to call after $rootscope.events is set
        $log.debug($rootScope.events); // debugging line
    }
});
```

I added the `$rootScope.events.length > 0` to avoid it's getting in a infinite loop. Not sure if this is necessary. Is there a solution for what I need to add this functionality? Something like this watch? Or have I done something wrong?

I don't think you need more code then I've added to this post as I just inject `$scope` and `$rootScope` in my controller, and then `$log.debug()` should get called with the set variable. Currently it returns an empty variable. If I'm wrong just let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile, but I think you want this:

```
$rootScope.$watch('events', function() {
    if ($rootScope.events.length > 0) {
        getDetails(); // function I want to call after $rootscope.events is set
        $log.debug($rootScope.events); // debugging line
    }
});
```

`events` is a value on `$rootscope` but `$rootscope.events` is *not* a value on `$scope`.

To avoid cluttering `$rootscope` with watches, however, you should probably use:

```
$scope.$watch('$root.events', function() {
    var events = $scope.$root.events;
    if (events.length > 0) {
        getDetails(); // function I want to call after events is set
        $log.debug(events); // debugging line
    }
});
```

Or simply:

```
$scope.$watch('$root.events', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue.length > 0) {
        getDetails(); // function I want to call after events is set
        $log.debug(newValue); // debugging line
    }
});
```

Comment: Wauww I was soo close. And this makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @JeroenE this should work using `$scope.$watch` and be safer. The watch from $rootScope will probably not be cleaned if this is put in a controller and the current route/state change. Leaving one/more watch each time you pass in this code slowing the application.

Comment: @JeroenE can use `$scope.$watch('$root.events', ...)` to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

[RootScope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Watch is on a string (scope variable) or a function.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
   return $rootScope.events;
}, function() {
   console.log($rootScope.events);
}, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great but what does the "return $rootScope.events"?

Comment: It is the value function parameter. See this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html#watch). It's basically an overload that expects a function which returns the value instead of a string which names the value.

Comment: Also, see the $watch documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a watch for something that happen once, you can use a promise which your events service will resolve when the events will be ready.

```
Event Service : ($rootScope & $q injected)
   // in constructor : 
     this.deferred = $q.defer();
     $rootScope.eventPromise = deferred.promise;


    // in a setup fonction or even within the constructor
    setupEvent : function(){
       .. doing some stuff ..
        .. somewhere in a asynchronous call back : 
            $rootScope.events =... //setup events
            this.deferred.resolve();// or me.deferred using var me=this if some closure trouble

       .. somewhere else if it fails ..
            this.deferred.reject();
    }
```

Now let's be sure this will run before any controller will be loaded :

```
angular.run(['EventService', function(EventService){
    // if you do everything in the constructor let the angular.run and don't run any code, 
    // this will make sure your events will start loading before angular will resolve the current routes.
    EventService.setupEvent();
}]);
```

Now let's use it :

```
$rootScope.eventPromise.then(function(){
    $rootScope.events // we're safe here.
});
```